# Oracles REGEXP_LIKE not working correctly?

Tags: regex, oracle

This could probably be something simple I'm missing but anyways:

I'm trying to match strings in a column that end with `'01'`. I currently have this for my expression `'[A-Z0-9\-]+01$'` which matches the types of strings I want matched checking with [regex101](https://regex101.com/). The strings it should be matching should be like this:

`1-WA01-0009-01`

which works in the linked site.

This is the SQL I'm using to test this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM V_Translog_MDATE_V1 
WHERE  
REGEXP_LIKE (ITEMNO, '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+01$')
ORDER BY ARINVT_ID
```

Why isn't my regex working in the SQL, in that why does this reutrn nothing when I know there are strings that match the pattern?

> Closed but not working

Nothing seemed out of place with I was doing so hoping it could be something to do with the columns values itself. Thanks for the help from those who tried.

Comment: Your regex actually [matches](http://rextester.com/VZZFH44134) `1-WA01-0009-01` in `1-WA01-0009-01` in Oracle. Are you sure you are using the right column/table names?

Comment: I'm sorry could you clarify that a little bit?

Comment: Why so complicated pattern? What about `.*01$`

Comment: @MarianD that is a better pattern. It was like that at the start, but as simple things weren't working it just got more convoluted as time went on if you know what I mean

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for your response too, but I'm unsure what you're pointing out with the 'Your regex actually matches 1-WA01-0009-01 in 1-WA01-0009-01 in Oracle'

Comment: So you didn't accurately describe what you wanted - not only `01` at the end but other restrictions, too.

Comment: @spyr0 Your regex matches the string you provided. That is what I mean.

Comment: @MarianD Sorry if it looks like that, but literally what I want is just anything that ended in 01. Everything before it I don't care. My problem is that what solutions there are and I've tried should work but they don't which is really confusing me. It may be something to do with formatting issues maybe so I might just close this, since nothing really stands out to people

Comment: Maybe your string(s) in you column ends with `O1` (as opposite of `01`)?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If I end up finding what was wrong I'll come back and update this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to match strings in a column that end with `'01'`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/628e0/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE V_Translog_MDATE_V1 ( ARINVT_ID, itemno ) AS
SELECT 1, '1-WA01-0009-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '1-WA01-0009-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '%&*^$%"£*&%-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '%&*^$%"£*&%-02' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

You could just use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   V_Translog_MDATE_V1 
WHERE  ITEMNO LIKE '%01'
ORDER BY ARINVT_ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/628e0/1/0)**:

```
| ARINVT_ID |         ITEMNO |
|-----------|----------------|
|         1 | 1-WA01-0009-01 |
|         3 | %&*^$%"£*&%-01 |
```

**Query 2**:

If you want to use regular expressions then you do not need to check the preceding characters:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   V_Translog_MDATE_V1 
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( ITEMNO,  '01$' )
ORDER BY ARINVT_ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/628e0/1/1)**:

```
| ARINVT_ID |         ITEMNO |
|-----------|----------------|
|         1 | 1-WA01-0009-01 |
|         3 | %&*^$%"£*&%-01 |
```

**Query 3**:

If you want the entire string to be matched by your acceptable preceding characters regular expression then you want to prefix it with `^` (start-of-string):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   V_Translog_MDATE_V1 
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( ITEMNO,  '^[A-Z0-9\-]+01$' )
ORDER BY ARINVT_ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/628e0/1/2)**:

```
| ARINVT_ID |         ITEMNO |
|-----------|----------------|
|         1 | 1-WA01-0009-01 |
```

(otherwise `[A-Z0-9\-]+01$` would match `£$£^*&$^"%-01` since there is at least one matched character preceding the final `01` characters.)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I've actually tried the two SQL statements above before already with `LIKE '%01'` and regex with just '01$' which is why I find this so odd

Comment: @spyr0 Updated with an SQL fiddle which shows the various queries in action.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It all looks correct. My problem is those queries should work and don't which is what is strange, but maybe it could be something to do with formatting possibly(hopefully?). Thanks for all the help anyways :)